# Looking for some javascript fragment explained

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I'm looking for piece of simple code precisely detailled because i think it's a great way to learn.

So do you know where i can find this kind of ressources ?

Thanks

Comment: Just google 'learn javascript'...

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) is a great place to get started.

Their [Javascript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) outlines what you need to know with the code examples you inquired about.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this site](http://jqueryair.com/) very usefull. Videos, with explanations, online console with exercises and hardness levels.